# How to delete a property from an Ext object?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How to delete a property from an Ext object ? For example :

```
Ext.define('Classes.Person', {status:'load',
    config: {
            name: 'Eugene',
            surname : 'Popov'
    },
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
    }
  });

var book = Ext.create('Classes.Person') 
/*
console.log(book.status)//load 
console.log( book.surname  )//Popov 
delete book.status
delete book.surname;
 console.log( book.surname  )//Popov 
 console.log(book.status)//load  How delete property ? 
 */
```

Is there a special method to do so?

Comment: if you do console.log(book) what do you get?

Comment: Why `book` for a person instance? Anyway, it's never a good idea to delete properties on objects. It makes your code run slower because your instances cannot share the same hidden classes (at least in V8). I believe Ext used `Object.defineProperty` to define objects properties. By default, properties defined that way are not `configurable`, meaning they cannot be deleted and the descriptor cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deleting property, delete the value of the property

```
console.log(book.status)//load 
console.log( book.surname  )//Popov 
book.status = undefined; //remove the existing value
book.surname = undefined;
console.log( book.surname  )//undefined 
console.log(book.status)//undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a property from an object in ExtJs just use 'delete' command, like in example:

```
delete book.status;
```

It deletes 'status' property from 'book' object.
I just checked it on my side and works perfectly.